# tool to remember window positions when I plug in/unplug an external display

Tags: macos, mac, display

When I have a giant Thunderbolt monitor plugged into my MacBook, I want windows arranged a certain way.  No full-screen apps, some apps are shown on my small laptop screen, other apps are shown on my Thunderbolt display.  When I unplug the Thunderbolt display, I would like programs arranged differently, e.g., the browser is a full-screen app.  Is there any program that will let me "save" my window state when I have an external monitor plugged in, and save another layout when I don't have any external display, and automatically switch between the two when it detects that external display has been plugged in or unplugged?  I'm on Mountain Lion on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 14):

[Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) allows giving windows different default positions depending on the connected displays. See the [developer's configuration file](https://github.com/jigish/dotfiles/blob/master/slate) for some examples.

Comment: +1 for a free and open source alternative.  I installed it and hope to be pleased.  It was also mentioned at the similar question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/

Answer (score 9):

### [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/)

by Cordless Dog. It saves window state for each display configuration you might have.

[image]

Comment: love it, will save me a lot of time faffing about

Comment: Stay is a great app, the functionality it offers solves exactly this problem,and it will fire automatically, causing your spaces to jump around when you unlock - it's a bit crazy, but fun and better than having to trigger it yourself every time.  The problem is that it doesn't always work (I'm running Mavericks) - some apps aren't supported, and I often find that some windows just don't resize.  If it was free I'd recommend it, but as a paid-for app I'd expect reliable performance.

Comment: It seemed like a good fit. But with 3 external displays it often had problems with the positions and just solved the problem to 50%.
So I still had to do a lot of manual work. I just deinstalled it.
Oh, and its only 30 day trial!

Answer (score 4):

## [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/)

Move, zoom, and snap windows. Auto-adjust to display setups. And more.