Which automation system would you use to automate Mission Control Spaces?
There are a number of different automation paths on MacOS, such as osascript, shortcut app, etc.
I wish to save a Mission Control Spaces "presets" set up - for example perhaps by double clicking on a desktop icon, using a keystroke or similar.
An ideal situation would be, when a monitor is connected/disconnected and/or at wake up, a script (?) runs which decides on how to set up Mission Control Spaces and/or choose from a "preset"
Is it possible?

Possible duplicates https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126351/remember-window-sizes-and-placement-when-unplugging-and-replugging-second-monito and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/how-do-i-make-windows-save-their-position-on-screen-after-re-attaching-a-display

cheers @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz hmm, the first one appears to be about windows ?  (No connection whgatsoever to what is being asked here?)  Sorry if I missed something, there's a lot of fluff to read through on that question.

cheers @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz the same seems to apply to the second one you mention?

As noted in your last question about this, Hammerspoon could be used to do this. Cheers.

@SteveM I appreciate that tip, thanks.  For me, I would not want to bother start installing and then maintaining a library like that, but the info may be useful to others, TY again!

BTW what id "topanswers.xyz" ??

As far as I know, Apple does not provide a public API for manipulating Spaces. Thus any tool able to do so would need to use private APIs. And since private APIs are not guaranteed to persist, few developers are willing to use them. I know of only two tools that can do what you are asking, the automation tool Hammerspoon and the window manager Yabai. Both require installation and setup. So if you are not willing to do so you're likely out of luck. (Better Touch Tool also has some Spaces functionality, but I'm not sure it can do what you are asking, but it may be worth a look as well.)

@SteveM - thanks for that great info!  Perhaps u should pop in an answer as it may well be useful to others.

As far as I know, Apple does not provide a public API for manipulating Spaces. Thus any tool able to do so would need to use private APIs. And since private APIs are not guaranteed to persist, few developers are willing to use them. I know of only two tools that can do what you are asking, the automation tool Hammerspoon and the window manager Yabai. Both require installation and setup. So if you are not willing to do so you're likely out of luck. (Better Touch Tool also has some Spaces functionality, but I'm not sure it can do what you are asking, but it may be worth a look as well.)
