# How do I make windows save their position after re-attaching a display?

Tags: macos, display

I know about [How do I make windows save their position on screen after re-attaching a display?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/how-do-i-make-windows-save-their-position-on-screen-after-re-attaching-a-display)

However, that and all other related questions appear to be very old, and I'm hoping that there's a new way to do this.

Same question though: I have a laptop, I usually use it with two monitors. Some windows I pretty much always have in the same places. Other windows float, or are temporary.

When I unplug the laptop to go to a meeting, everything goes to the laptop screen. When I plug it back into the monitors, everything is on one monitor, and I have to go around moving everything back...

I'd like it to just remember where it was when I unplugged without having to explicitly save something, because it's not always going to be the same. I just want it to be as I left it...

Reasons the previous answer isn't satisfying:

1) it's 5 years old. What 5 year old answer is still valid in tech?

2) the program suggested: Stay, seems inefficient. It requires that I save a specific window layout each time. I just want it to go back to whatever I had before I unplugged. Stay appears to minimize all windows that weren't part of the saved settings, which is not really what I want.

3) I am **REALLY** hoping that in the last 5 years, macOS had fixed this problem, so the solution wasn't to use some other program, but to make some settings change.

Comment: Please be more specific about why the existing question (and its answers) doesn't cover your requirements here.

Comment: the "Stay" program which is recommended there doesn't work the way I would like (you have to explicitly save things) and I'm hoping that something new has happened in the last 5 years...

Comment: Place edit this into the question, it will be automatically placed in the Reopen review queue.